# Display data from database?

Tags: angularjs

I retrieve data from two tables from database.

Here how looks retrieved data in the client :

```
    this.courses = [
      { id: 1, text: 'Math' },
      { id: 2, text: 'Physics' },
    ];

    this.students = [
      { id: 1, courseId: 2, text: 'John' },
      { id: 2, courseId: 2, text: 'Willi' },
      { id: 3, courseId: 2, text: 'Inga' },
      { id: 4, courseId: 1, text: 'Jerry' },
      { id: 5, courseId: 1, text: 'Michael' },
    ];
```

I want to display it this way:

[image]

My question what is the elegant way in AngularJS display data that has foreign key association?

Comment: the `idForgien` field is pointing to a course id?

Comment: It might be best to craft and return a better viewmodel to avoid situations like this

Comment: you probably want to write a filter to group your students by courses

Comment: If i were you, i resolver from your db grouped by course id, and that should return a lis of courses grouped , do then would be easy to use ng repeat. But i think could be a backend solution before front. Regards

Comment: No need to write one. Just use `filter:{idForgien: currentCourse.id}`. But that will be quite inefficient. I agree with @salniro

Comment: @salniro what situations?

Comment: figuring out how to join your model when this should be done on the backend and returned as such to avoid JS manipulation

Comment: @salniro why better to implement it in server side and not on client side?\

Comment: @Michael updated my answer with an explanation about your last question + a better way to deal with your mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old answer**

The easiest way to achieve it, is just nesting `ng-repeat` with an `ng-if`.

```
<div ng-repeat="course in controller.courses">
    <span ng-bind="::course.text" />
    <div ng-repeat="student in controller.students" ng-if="student.courseId == course.id">
         <span ng-bind="::student.text" />
    </div>

</div>
```

An other solution would be to implement a filter.

ps : Usually, in angular, the view is strongly dependent to the view model returned by the back-end. The reason for this is the need to have all the business logic located in 1 layer of your application.
But, there is nothing wrong if your back-end is just a kind of web-service, with all the logic inside the client. It's just more difficult to debug, and hackers can also read your business logic.

**Updated answer**

You asked for the most elegant way to achieve your mapping inside the angular application. I think dealing with your data inside a service would be the best option.

```
angular.module('myApp').service("SomeServiceName", ['$q', '$http', function($q, $http){ 
    var service = {
        getStudentsInCourses: getStudentsInCourses
    };

    return service;

    function getStudentsInCourses(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var promises = [];
        promises.push($http.get('myUrlToMyCourses'));
        promises.push($http.get('myUrlToMyStudents'));

        $q.all(promises).then(function(results){
            var courses = results[0];
            var students = results[1];
            for (var i = 0; i <= courses.length; ++i){
                courses[i].students = [];
                for(var j = 0; j...){
                    // Push your students in your courses ;-)
                }
            }
            deferred.resolve(courses);

        }, function(error){
            //Handle error
        });


        return deferred.promise;
    }

}]);
```